# Python datetime ValueError: year 0 is out of range

Tags: python, date, datetime

I want to get the number of days since year 0, january 1st.

When I use `datetime(0, 1, 1).date()` I get : `ValueError: year 0 is out of range`

I want to find out the number of days passed since then.

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_1 = datetime(0, 1, 1).date()

date_2 = datetime.today().date()

delta = None
delta = date_2 - date_1
print("Difference is", delta.days, "days")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `datetime` for years <= 0.

A solution would be to set the year to 1 and add 365 (or 366 if leap) days to the counter.

```
from datetime import datetime

date_1 = datetime(1, 1, 1).date()

date_2 = datetime.today().date()

delta = None
delta = date_2 - date_1
print("Difference is", delta.days + 365 , "days") #366 if leap
```